# How to install an purchased app on SharePoint 2013 dev environment without dns?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, app

I have a single server development environment. I do not have DNS. I have IIS and host file.

I would like to install an app on my development environment. It still would not work. I got this error when I try to add the app to a site collection.

```
SPException thrown: Message: The App domain for this site has already been assigned.. Stack:   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.ThrowSPExceptionWithTraceTag(UInt32 tagId, ULSCat traceCategory, String resourceId, Object[] resourceArgs)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.EnsureAppSiteDomainPrefix(Guid id, String subscriptionName, Boolean overwrite, String appSiteDomainIdToUse, String& newAppSiteDomainId, List`1& siteUrls)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.EnsureAppSiteDomainPrefix(Boolean overwrite)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Packaging.SPUserCodeSolutionDeploymentGroup.Deploy()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAppTask.DeployOperation()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Lifecycle.MonitoredTaskExecution.DoTask()    
 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)    
 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)    
 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    
 at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

I did already this configuration:

1. I go to central admin
2. I click on apps
3. I click on app catalog
4. I selected some webapplication
5. I created a new app catalog "http://myCompany.com/sites/MyAppCatalog
6. I did created the subscription service application with powershell
7. I set the "Configure App URLs" as follow: domain: appsMyCompany.com, prefix: app.
8. I set this domain "appsMyCompany.com" in the host file.
9. I created a new webapplication with the url: appsMyCompany.com

UPDATE

When I add the app as an instance in the app catalog (on Site Contents page), it is working. When I click on the app I get an 404 error. This is because the subdomain which the app instance is using is not exist in IIS. (http://app-04ab54ab4d69a7.appsMyCompany.com/sites/MyAppCatalog/AppCompanyAdvancedAnalytics/Pages/Default.aspx?SPHostUrl=http......some stuff)

Do I need to add some wildcard binding to the webapplication appsMyCompany.com ? Or do I need to add a binding with the url app-04ab54ab4d69a7.appsMyCompany.com to the webapplication appsMyCompany.com.

Comment: what you enter in the host file app.appsbrabantwater.nl or appsbrabantwater.nl?

Comment: I add appsMyCompany.com. See also my update.

Comment: did you added that url in AAM as well? check this http://www.ashokraja.me/post/Develop-SharePoint-2013-Napa-App-In-Local-Dev-Environment-Configuring-On-Premises-without-DNS.aspx

Comment: It is still not working. Also with the url in AAM.

Comment: IT works! I have created a new webapplication for the app domain. In iis I add the wildcard character (*). In the host file I add the app domain url, but also the url of the app instance: app-04ab54ab4d69a7.appsMyCompany.com.

Comment: great, did that article helped?

Comment: i added those steps as an anwser so that community get the benefit and some rewards for me

Answer (score 1):

As You Dont have the  DNS then you need to add the host file entry.Add your App domain in the host file.

- Add the  "appsMyCompany.com" into host file.
- Disable the loopbackcheck on server
- Add the apps url into web application's AAM settings.
- Edit the IIS Bindings

Please read complete step over here.[Develop SharePoint 2013 Napa App In Local Dev Environment (Configuring On Premises without DNS)](http://www.ashokraja.me/post/Develop-SharePoint-2013-Napa-App-In-Local-Dev-Environment-Configuring-On-Premises-without-DNS.aspx#sthash.h7eKfxi5.dpuf)